# Menu not sliding out on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a menu that's supposed to slide out on mobile units when I click a button, but it's no longer working since I made it so that the menu and button is added via AJAX instead of directly in the markup.

Here's the code:

Check the current screen (window for now) size and call the function that grabs the files:

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width(); //Will be screen.width later, using window for testing

if (windowWidth < 550) {

    getPhpFile('mobilemenu', '#main-nav-container', 'insertAfter');
    getPhpFile('mobmenuimg', '#main-nav-container', 'append');
}
```

This function grabs the files and calls the function that adds it to the HTML if successful:

```
function getPhpFile(filename, selector, method) {

    $.ajax({
        url : "includes/" + filename + ".php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            appendToHtml(data, selector, method);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('Unable to get the requested files.');
        }
    });
}
```

Adds the data from the grabbed file to the HTML:

```
function appendToHtml(data, selector, method) {
        var element = $('' + selector + '');

    switch (method) {
        ...
        //Some removed cases here
        ...
        case 'append': element.append(data); 
                        break;

        case 'insertAfter': $(data).insertAfter(element); 
                        break;
    }
}
```

This is what makes the menu slide out:

```
$('#mobile-nav-btn').on('click', function() {

    if ($('#mobile-nav-container').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#mobile-nav-container').stop().show().animate({left: 0}, 'slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#mobile-nav-container').stop().animate({left: -150}, 'slow', function() {
            $('#mobile-nav-container').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

I've narrowed my search down to the fact that it can't find `#mobile-nav-btn` for some reason. This because the script actually works when I use something other than the button to trigger the sliding function. I find this a bit weird though since the button and the menu are in fact in the markup when I check the console, and I don't run the script until the markup is there since it's trigged via a click event. I tried using an `window.onload = init` for the sliding script as well but it did nothing. Everything is encapsulated in an `$(document).ready` function as well. I'm really stuck on how to fix this so any tips on what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to bind your event to an element that doesn't exist. You can either use event delegation on a parent element of the nav button using event delegation syntax:

`$('parent-element').on('click','#mobile-nav-button', function(){ ....`

Or you have to bind your events after you have added those elements to the DOM.

Comment: But shouldn't a init function run after the window has finished loading do the exact same thing? Cuz then I'm binding the event after everything else is done. It doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Your button is being loaded asynchronously, no? Anything loads after the fact isn't included in document.ready or window.load

Comment: If you put a console.log in window.load, document.ready and the callback of your ajax call, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: ah right, forgot that it loads asynchronous.. kinda obvious when using AJAX duh.. I'll try to fix it

Comment: I would bind the event in the callback personally, as I'm unsure if you have a parent target available for delegation.